# Trying to add array list for Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android programming and I cant understand the problem 
[problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtOw6.png)
and another one here
[proplem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOb0M.png)

Comment: First, please do not post images of error messages or code but include it in your question. These errors in your picture are not android or android-studio specific but pure java. In "Problem 1" you're trying to call a non-existing constructor of the super class, in "Problem 2" you mismatched return types. I would recommend familiarizing with the java basics and voting to close this question as too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Android programming but I think you put in the wrong generic value. You wrote

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WordAdapter> {
     //...
}
```

Maybe it should be

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
     //...
}
```

This would fix both problems.